# I already have OpenCV C++ installed. Can I use its functions in Python without reinstalling the library?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, installation

To begin with, I am setting up environment for a machine-learning project. I plan to use tensorflow for the training, and opencv for data acquisition as well as pre-processing. In a prior project, I already have opencv installed in C++, but this time I want to keep all my code in python in order to make everything clean.

Is my plan achievable? Do I need to reconfigure or recompile the library? If so, is there a way to make  the existing opencv library work with python?

If you have a better suggestion, you are welcome to post it below.

Info about my current system:

- OSX 10.13.6
- opencv 3.4.3 (installed with homebrew)
- python 3.6.10

Comment: You can use pip to install `opencv-python`. Why do you need to compile the library?

Comment: @ranka47 I do know that I can use pip to install, but will that makes me download the entire library again?

Comment: Yes, you cant use the c++ Opencv library with Python.

Comment: Its possible but you need to have a really deep knowledge of those languages. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) is your answer I think

Comment: @Yunus Temurlenk I checked your link. Is that means I need to write the wrapper every time when I want to use the opencv function? Can I just import the c++ library to python as a package?

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont have an idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation will be necessary only for the bindings. The python wrapper is generated from OpenCV's source. The stub code that gets generated has to be linked against Python and the OpenCV libraries.

The process starts with the Cmake file at `modules/python/CMakeFiles.txt` which shall define the list of modules that needs to be made available from Python. Next, the headers are grabbed and parsed from these by a python bindings generator script resident within OpenCV's source structure. The headers shall include function declarations etc which shall then be converted into wrapper functions by the same generator script.

You could try to modify the cmake to exclude/include any module that you do not want to compile and build the bindings. This will not recompile OpenCV

Please have a look at : [OpenCV Python Bindings](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) to understand in detail how the python bindings are being generated.